# Crystal Server CrystalDecisions.Enterprise in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, crystal-reports, gac

I have a .NET 4 Website (not application) in which I'm trying to use Crystal Reports Server's InfoStore DLL so I can query the  production server.  The server is running SAP Crystal Server 2011.

The dev machine is running Windows 8 64bit running Visual Studio 2010 and the Crystal Server Runtime environment x64, downloaded from my account at http://service.sap.com.

I can see *CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.InfoStore* and *CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework* in the GAC at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64, and it I click 'Add Reference' and select it by browsing it adds **<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.InfoStore, Version=14.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>** to web.config.  Which is how I would expect it to happen.

The problem is, despite being able to browse the object in Object Browser, when I attempt to build the site it always results in:

*Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.InfoStore, Version=14.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.  C:\Users\lee\Documents\Projects\app\web.config*

I've been tearing my hair out for the last 8 hours, trying to figure out why and I'm at a loss so any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: what are your build configuration settings? ANY_CPU, x86, x64?

Comment: ANY_CPU.  But I don't appear to have the option to force x64.

Comment: Duplicate (Cross Post of) Question off-site http://scn.sap.com/thread/3260013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorted it.  I had to do a few things so thought it'd be best to document them for others.

1. Uninstall Crystal Server Runtime environment x64 and install the x86 version instead.  Despite it being a x64 environment Visual Studio 2010 is 32bit and requires this.
2. The install is broken and requires a batch file to be run to correct it (see here http://scn.sap.com/thread/3175725)
3. Ensure your Application Pool allows 32bit.  By default it's 64 bit only.